# Creating Multiple Workfile using Bash Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I m trying to create a multiple workfiles

Source csv file

```
**Filename,SchemaName,TableName 
Shelf,category,books 
Door,Category,wood**
```

Expected Output

```
each Filename from column 1

Shelfy.wrk

\`File content  Shelf.wrk

Your table is category.books\`

Door.wrk

\`File content  Door.wrk

Your table is category.wood\`
```

I tried to create something like

```
sed 's/,/\\n/g' file | while read fileName; do touch "$fileName".wrk; done
```

but not sure how to populate the content by form row by row to seperate file

Comment: I wouldn't use `sed` at all. Loop instead over the lines of your source csv, split each line on the comma (i.e. `IFS=,`), and read the fields into variables. You have then in each iteration of the loop the filename, the category, and the tablename, and can use these variables to create your file with the desired content.

Comment: awk -F, 'FNR>1 {system("echo -e  \"\\\\\\`File content  "$1".wrk  \\nYour table is category."$3"\\\\\\`\" > " $1".wrk")}' source.csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user1934428 mentioned, there's no need to use sed at all, but awk.

```
awk '(NR!=1)' source.csv | awk -F, '{fName=$1".wrk";cat=$2;tbl=$3; print fName"\nFile content "fName"\nYour table is "cat"."tbl}'
```

First let's skip the first line with `awk '(NR!=1)' source.csv`
Then instruct awk to use comma as field separator with `-F,` (as IFS=, would do)
Assign each column value to a variable. For file name extension .wrk is appended: `fName=$1".wrk"`. For the other two columns: `cat=$2;tbl=$3;`

Finally you only print the strings
`print fName"\nFile content "fName"\nYour table is "cat"."tbl`